# Kotlin map function changes all child objects on first iteration

Tags: java, spring, kotlin

I have a problem where I am trying to iterate over an array of objects and change all images to base64 including child objects. When I do so, the objects (Job) get changed one by one as a map function is expected to, but when I want the changed every iterations child object it does something weird. At the first iteration, the first object (Job) converts the image correctly, but when the map tried to change the child object (Company) it changes all other parent objects (Job) child objects (Company) that have a reference to the image, so when the second iteration starts the references to the images are gone and the application crashes (But only all the child references (Company) get changed at first iteration).

Visual representation:

Start first iteration: http://prntscr.com/18ijsnq

End of the first iteration: http://prntscr.com/18ik1cy

Start of the second iteration: http://prntscr.com/18ik97w

As you can see the company child objects have changed for all Job objects in the array, but I expect it to change one by one for every iteration.

This is my data model:

[image]

Code with map:

```
    @GetMapping
fun getAllJobs(): ResponseEntity<*> {
    return try {
        val jobList: List<Job> = jobRepository.findAll()
        jobList.map {
            val file = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(File("images/job/" + it.jobImage))
            val companyFile = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(File("images/company/" + it.company.logo))
            it.company.logo = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(companyFile)
            it.jobImage = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(file)
        }
        JsonDataResponse(HttpStatus.OK, "Retrieved lists of jobs ", jobList).createResponseEntity()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        JsonResponse(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, e.stackTraceToString()).createResponseEntity()
    }
}
```

My attempt with mapIndexed:

```
    @GetMapping
fun getAllJobs(): ResponseEntity<*> {
    return try {
        val jobList: List<Job> = jobRepository.findAll()
        jobList.mapIndexed { i: Int, job: Job ->
            val file = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(File("images/job/" + job.jobImage))
            val companyFile = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(File("images/company/" + jobList[i].company.logo))
            jobList[i].company.logo = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(companyFile)
            job.jobImage = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(file)
        }
        JsonDataResponse(HttpStatus.OK, "Retrieved lists of jobs ", jobList).createResponseEntity()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        JsonResponse(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, e.stackTraceToString()).createResponseEntity()
    }
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: File 'images\company\data:image\jpeg;base64,\9j\4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD...AAAAAAH\Z' does not exist
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.openInputStream(FileUtils.java:297) ~[commons-io-2.6.jar:2.6]
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(FileUtils.java:1851) ~[commons-io-2.6.jar:2.6]
    at com.example.bouwershub.controllers.JobController.getAllJobs(JobController.kt:32) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at....
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: obviously, `Company` object is shared between different `jobs`. you cannot have different logo for same `company` in different `Job` objects. PS: shouldn't be using `map` for this activity

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on what I should do instead?